# Como corrigir erros de dependência na instalação do ng-bootstrap em um projeto Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, npm

Estou com problemas para fazer a instalação da dependência @ng-bootstrap. Atualmente utilizo Debian e VScode.

Ao executar o código: `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` o retorno é um erro de conflito de dependências no package @ng-bootstrap.

Erro do npm ao tentar instalar a dependência:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: diretivas-angular@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@13.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"13.3.9" from @angular/localize@13.3.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   dev @angular/localize@"^13.2.7" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/localize@"^13.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/gropp/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

*Detalhe: para eu conseguir rodar o projeto sem outros erros, preciso ter essa dependência.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como o próprio log de erro sugere, você pode corrigir os conflitos e erros de dependência utilizando o comando `--force` ou `--legacy-peer-deps`.

**SOLUÇÃO 1 -**
Geralmente o comando `--legacy-peer-deps` tende a funcionar, você pode tentar adiciona-lo no final do seu comando npm, por exemplo: `npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps`.

**SOLUÇÃO 2 -**
Uma outra opção se acima não funcionar, você pode tentar baixar o angular globalmente pelo comando:
`npm install -g @angular/cli`
e em seguida utilizar o angular para adicionar o @ng-bootstrap ao angular e ao seu projeto:

`ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` ou
`ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --project myProject`

Como mostra nessa [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap).

**SOLUÇÃO 3 -**
Apague a pasta `/node_modules`, que é a pasta responsável por guardar suas dependências, em seguida refaça a instalação de todas deps usando `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`, se a dependência @ng-bootstrap não estiver no arquivo package.json, você deve executar `npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps` novamente para instalar e adicionar a dependência ao package.json.

Se nada funcionar, uma quarta saída seria você diminuir a versão do seu node, em alguns casos pessoais de instalação de dependências muito antigas funcionou.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação. Como era muita informação e como estou começando agora no web desenvolvimento, ficou confuso o retorno do erro. Executei o comando com os parâmetros de legacy, instalou o ng-bootstrap, mas isso ocasionou algumas coisas inesperadas. A primeira é que não consegui fazer funcionar o dito popup dos botões, o segundo problema é que todas as chamadas de diretivas [ngStyle] e [ngClass] pararam de funcionar, o VSCode está acusando que não são propriedades das tag essas diretivas. Você sabe o que tem que fazer para arrumar? Agradeço antecipadamente.

Comment: Esse erro é bem abrangente, sem o log de erro fica complicado te ajudar com mais detalhes, mas talvez a solução 3 seja uma saída.

Comment: Obrigado novamente meu amigo. Eu desisti do ng-bootstrap. Reinstalei novamente o angular, refiz o projeto e parei de inventar. Vou estudar mais um pouco esses frameworks para aprender como funciona.